# Attempting to rotate points in lat-long, but only achieving a rotation around the 'Z' axis

Tags: python, matlab, rotation, latitude-longitude, rotational-matrices

I have some points in the [ECEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) coordinate frame, and would like to rotate them by a given latitude and longitude. The basic idea of what I'm attempting is

```
rotated_vector = Rz(longitude_in_radians) * Rx(latitude_in_radians) * vector
```

where `vector` is a 3x1 ECEF position, and Rz and Rx are 3x3 matrices defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations).

The basic problem I'm getting is that the rotation around the Z axis is as expected, but the vector does not seem to rotate around the X axis.

I've attempted this in both Python and Matlab, and I'm getting the same result in both.

My Matlab code is as follows, as it's a bit shorter than my python code

```matlab
close; clc; clear; 

R     = 6378; %earth radius
r     = 500; 
alt   = 200; %altitude of point
d     = R + alt; %offset of small sphere along x axis
alpha = 1/(2*d)*sqrt(4*d^2*R^2-(d^2-r^2+R^2)^2); %radius of circle intersection of two spheres

%% plotting spheres
[x,y,z] = sphere; %data for sphere of radius 1 at 0,0,0
figure
surf(R*x,R*y,R*z) %plot earth
hold on

%% plot the circle of intersection

theta = 0 : 0.01 : 2*pi;
yc    = alpha*cos(theta);
zc    = alpha*sin(theta);
xc    = theta*0 + sqrt(R^2 - alpha^2);

plot3(xc,yc,zc,'r', 'LineWidth',6)
axis equal

%% carry out the rotation
theta_z = 90 * pi/180;
theta_x = 45 * pi/180; % no matter what I enter here, the vector never leaves the x-y plane
theta_y = theta_x;

Rx = [1,            0,            0  ;
      0, cos(theta_x), -sin(theta_x) ;
      0, sin(theta_x),  cos(theta_x)];

Ry = [cos(theta_y), 0, sin(theta_y);
      0           , 1,          0  ;
      -sin(theta_y), 0, cos(theta_y)];

Rz = [cos(theta_z), -sin(theta_z), 0;
      sin(theta_z),  cos(theta_z), 0;
      0           ,             0, 1];

rotated = Rz * Rx * [xc; yc; zc];
plot3(rotated(1,:), rotated(2,:), rotated(3,:), 'r', 'LineWidth',6)
```

Comment: I believe I've discovered part of the problem. My points are in a ring around the x-axis. When I multiply Rx by the vectors, I just rotate the ring, and after, the points are still around the x-axis. Is this gimble lock? How can I get past it?